# when cell contains then

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I have a range: M2:M & aantalrijen. For this range, I want to have a value in each cell based on the value in the same cell in column E. I have a script which defines the total range in the workbook and I want to use that number of filled rows to fill column M with the right value. I have this script, but it doesn't  work. (vba does not help me finding my mistakes). How can I make this code work? the code:

```
  With Sheets("sheet1")
    aantalrijen = .Range("A1", .Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Cells.Count

    For Each cell In .Range("M2:M" & aantalrijen)
    If CStr(.Cells(aantalrijen, -8)) = "*zeezout*" Then .Cells(aantalrijen, 0) = "Zeezout"
    Next cell
  End With
```

What is the right code?

Comment: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: The `If` line looks very weird, but first things first. Notice you never use the loop variable `cell` in your loop? And what exactly do you want to test, if the cell is equal to "\*zeezout\*" or are you trying to use wildcards to match anything that contains "zeezout"? You are also calling `Cells` with a negative value, I guess by -8 you meant to check column E as `M - 8 = E`. Go into your VBE help and read up on `Cells`, `Offset`, `Like`. And probably read a book to get you started on the basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a code a consultant created for me 2 weeks ago which filled an entire range with a formula. I tried to use this formula, but as you point out: I do not know enough of the basics. I found out again today. I have fixed it now because it was something that could be done by creating a regular excel formula. Searching on google for vba and if or vba and containts helped me create and excel formula for one cell. I then recorded it with the macro recorder to see what cell references are used and then pasted it in my macro code. –